# Null values in plugin data source

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, .net

How do you appropriately setup a plugin data source to allow for null values (in .NET - C# preferred)?

I'm currently setting up a field using:

```
field.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeSingle;
field.IsNullable_2 = true;
field.Name_2 = "Foo";
```

Then, later, during the cursor's QueryValues call, I'm trying to set a null value via:

```
// Given: public int QueryValues(IRowBuffer row)
row.Value[i] = null;
```

However, the value always maps through as 0, not null.  How do you properly setup the data source in a plugin data source to allow for a null value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried setting [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx) instead of `null`?

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't tried that, as their examples show setting it to `null` directly - but this does actually work (where the other doesn't).

Comment: The documentation is sometimes null and void :)  Do you have a link to this example?

Comment: I believe most of the .NET samples were converted from VB rather badly, perhaps semi-automatically I guess. In .NET COM interop, the VT_NULL (Null in VB/VBA) variant, which is used for denoting null values, maps directly to DBNull in .NET.