# How to insert DateTime null using IRowBuffer

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I am using IRowBuffer/IFeatureBuffer to insert fields to SQL Server 2008 DB.
When inserting a field I am using:

```
public void SetValue(IRowBuffer buffer, string field, object value)
{
   int fieldIndex = buffer.Fields.FindField(field);
   buffer.set_Value(fieldIndex, value ?? DBNull.Value);
}
```

(meaning when inserting null value I am using DBNull.Value)

Using this code with integer/float fields with null value works without a problem.
But using this with DateTime result in the value:
01/01/0001 00:00:00
in the DB.

Edit: a bit more clarification
When using:

```
buffer.set_Value(10, DBNull.Value);
```

When 10 is the index for a nullable int field the DB has a value of null.
But when 10 is the index for a nullable datetime field the DB has a value of 01/01/0001 00:00:00 .
It's not a problem in .Net or using nullable types but rather a problem with ArcOjects.
I have already seen [Null values in plugin data source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6381/null-values-in-plugin-data-source)

Do someone have a solution for this?
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why did you just not send null?

Comment: A limitation in set_value, see: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6381/null-values-in-plugin-data-source

Comment: Have you tried putting a null value into your SQL Server DB manually? Does it work?

Comment: Can you set the date field to null using the field calculator in arcmap?

Comment: From ArcMap trying to enter both ' '(space) and <Null> failed.

Comment: Sounds like an ArcObjects bug. Report it :)

Answer (score 2):

Check `IField.IsNullable` before attempting to set a null value.

If you expected the field to be nullable, but IsNullable is false, then the field was defined incorrectly.  If you are creating the field programmatically, then set `IFieldEdit2.IsNullable` to true.  If you add it through the ArcMap UI, then make sure the *Allow NULL values* flag is set to *Yes*.